# SecurityAccessDenied exception while accessing WCF service in IssuedTokenOverTransport authentication mode

Tags: wcf-security

I have a WCF service hosted in my local IIS and I'm trying to access it from my windows application. The binding uses the authentication mode as 'IssuedTokenOverTransport'

I have another service hosted in the same IIS which issues a SAML token. Windows application first calls this service, takes the SAML token issued by this service and uses the same token to call the WCF service.

There is no problem in getting the SAML token. But when WCF service is called with the same SAML token, I get the 'SecurityAccessDenied' exception : 'At least one security token in the message could not be validated.'

Can someone help me t get rid of this issue? I want to access service over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the server certificate. In web.config, the server certificate was configured with the certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust". This was expecting this server certificate in the ‘Trusted People’ store and it was not available there. When I copied it there, the problem got resolved !